# Нужна ли запятая перед тире для отделения главной части в СПП

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, спп

Уже задавал похожий вопрос, но так и не получил чёткого ответа.

**Если ты сразу устроился в компанию своей мечты, где и функционал интересный, и платят щедро[,] — ты счастливчик.**

**Если есть проблема, но в данную секунду ты находишься там, откуда не можешь её решить[,] — забудь о ней.**

Придаточные части осложнены и имеют свои придаточные, так что ставить просто запятую нельзя — нужно как-то отделить главную часть после обилия запятых, тем более что перед ней делается пауза. Для этого используется тире. Но поглощает ли она запятую, которая закрывает последнюю придаточную часть, или запятая перед тире всё же нужна?

В данной примере у Розенталя тире поглощает запятую:

*Он, чтобы показать, что всё это знает и со всем согласен, что он далёк от каких-либо сомнений — тут же предложил свои услуги.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Розенталя тире может и отдохнуть. Оно не "поглотило" запятую, а заменило её, - это немножко не о том, да? Авторский знак у Р.

Не смотрела, чем Р. это объясняет; возможно - инверсией.

Ога, нашла. Но несогласная я... Однако Р. ***рекомендует, но не настаивает,*** за что ему честь и хвала.

---

Условия, **благоприятствующие** постановке тире [(пункт 4)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142):

> ...перечисление придаточных частей: *Если не уверен в себе, если не
>   хватает мужества — откажись; Кругом люди, и кто зачем пришёл, у кого
>   какое дело — неясно; А что творилось в этом хаосе вещей, как он в нём
>   разбирался — уму непостижимо; Он, чтобы показать, что всё это знает и
>   со всем согласен, что он далёк от каких-либо сомнений — тут же
>   предложил свои услуги*.

Но в приведённых в вопросе примерах нетути "перечисления придаточных частей", так что и зап и тире на месте:

*Если ты сразу устроился в компанию своей мечты, где и функционал интересный, и платят щедро, — ты счастливчик.*

*Если есть проблема, но в данную секунду ты находишься там, откуда не можешь её решить, — забудь о ней.*

[Правило в справочнике РАН:](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg124.php)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание: ***"может ставиться"***! Следовательно, *может и не ставиться*...

---

Полное изложение темы у Р. см.:

[§ 38. Тире в сложноподчинённом предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142)

Comment: А какой у нас случай из пяти?

Comment: А тире всё-таки нужно, как считаете?

Comment: Тире у Р. мне ужасно не нравится; что открылось запятой (два придаточных), ею должно и закрываться; но Р. ставит тире как более сильный интонационный знак, увы не *вместе*, а *вместо* запятой; тот же смысл несёт тире и приведённых Вами примерах (а в первом случае ещё и повторённое "ты" работает в пользу постановки тире). Я люблю тире как "красивый" знак, резкопаузный. То есть ни под какие правила не подводила бы; тире остаётся на усмотрение автора.

Comment: М_Г! У нас никакого случая из пяти. Есть (в вопросе) три предложения: два от Василия, одно, железобетонное, пример из Р. И эти три тире мотивируются разными причинами. У Р. мне не хватает запятой, но он заменил её более сильным знаком; однако предложение начинается не с придаточных, а - с подлежащего "он". Красиво, имхо, смотрелось бы так: *Он — чтобы показать, что всё это знает и со всем согласен, что он далёк от каких-либо сомнений — тут же предложил свои услуги*. Ну не могу я пережить, чтобы что открыто запятой закрывалось бы тире!

Comment: А разве в вашем варианте после "сомнений" не нужна запятая, чтобы закрыть придаточное перед тире во вставной конструкции?

Comment: Нужна; это я увлеклась оформительством... О_о